# BigQuery _TABLE_SUFFIX is empty/missing tables

Tags: google-bigquery

Thanks in advance for taking a look into this, hope someone can help.

I am creating tables with fixed prefix + dynamic suffix
something like: name123456 in which name is fixed/static and 123456 is an incremental numeric value

I currently have multiple tables like:
name123456
name123457
name123458

And I am trying to dynamically query the most recent one (which is the one with the biggest suffix), in the given example it's "name123458".

When running the query below in the BigQuery UI:

```
#standardsql
select array_agg(distinct _TABLE_SUFFIX) from `project.dataset.name*`
```

I get no result, and (as far as I understand) I should get all the listed tables above.

I know to get the most recent one I need to use a WHERE clause with max(_TABLE_SUFFIX) but since I am getting an empty _TABLE_SUFFIX I can not get anything from it.

Let me know if more information is required and I'll update as needed.

Comment: Does the user running the query have access to the name tables? Are the name tables [external tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables#creating_a_table_that_references_an_external_data_source) or [views](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/views-intro)?

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your comment, I am the one who created the project/dataset/table so yes, I have full access and no, tables are not external, I keep testing and I think I found the issue, my tables were empty (Just schema) and it seems that BigQuery _TABLE_SUFFIX ignores empty tables. I'll confirm if  that's the issue since I don't see that documented anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution by myself so I'll share the solution here as an answer, but first, thanks to David and Martin Weitzmann for their time and help.

The problem with _TABLE_SUFFIX ignoring some tables/not returning something was that the tables I had in the dataset were all empty tables (just schema).

That's it, _TABLE_SUFFIX ignores empty tables, hope it helps someone else.

Comment: Just to explain the reason behind this behavior. _TABLE_SUFFIX is a pseudo-column, and it's added to every row that is read. Since no rows are read from the empty tables, no _TABLE_SUFFIX from the empty tables will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `_TABLE_SUFFIX` in your `SELECT` statement - only in the `WHERE` clause. But you can instead use metatables to find the most recent one: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-tables

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for your answer, I read somewhere else that `_TABLE_SUFFIX` can not be used in the `SELECT` statement but I can actually use it, the query I included in my question works well now that I have tables with data.